# Cascaded left join in LINQ

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I need to associate the nearest action (if any) to each node. The SQL query bellow do this for me:

```
select n.*, o.* from Nodes n
left outer join (
  select min(s.ActionAt) as ActionAt, min(s.Ahead) as Ahead, s.NodeId
  from SuggestedActions s
  group by s.NodeId
) o1 
  on o1.NodeId=n.Id
left outer join SuggestedActions o 
  on o.NodeId=o1.NodeId and o.ActionAt=o1.ActionAt and o.Ahead=o1.Ahead
```

But I'm not able to formulate the same query using LINQ. I've left join which selects nearest actions and I don't know how to continue with joining more data:

```
from node in db.Nodes
join no in db.SuggestedActions on node.Id equals no.NodeId into no1
from o1 in no1.DefaultIfEmpty()
group o1 by node.Id into go1
select new {
  NodeId = go1.Key,
  ActionAt = go1.Min(c => c.ActionAt),
  Ahead = go1.Min(c => c.Ahead)
} ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with this, it's not tested, but might give you a direction:

```
var nodeActions = from node in db.Nodes
    join action in db.SuggestedActions on node.Id equals action.NodeId into actions
    from action in actions.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new { node, action };

var minNodes = from nodeAction in nodeActions
    group nodeAction by nodeAction.node.Id
    into groupedActions
    select new
    {
        NodeId = groupedActions.Key,
        ActionAt = groupedActions.Min(c => c.action.ActionAt),
        Ahead = groupedActions.Min(c => c.action.Ahead)
    };

var result = from minNode in minNodes
    join nodeAction in nodeActions on new { Id = minNode.NodeId, minNode.ActionAt, minNode.Ahead }
        equals new { nodeAction.node.Id, nodeAction.action.ActionAt, nodeAction.action.Ahead } into nodeActionJ
    from action in nodeActionJ
    select action;
```

Comment: Thanks for the idea: I didn't know I can split LINQ query to multiple IQueryables and EF will emit a single SQL command. pf